# Unable to generate non-Latin Characters using Google TTS

Tags: python, csv, google-cloud-platform, unicode, text-to-speech

I have created a python script to generate audio using a .csv as a data source. The script has been validated when generating English/Spanish audio, but I can't get to generate words in Telegu.

My .csv file is in utf-8, and my script specifies utf-8, but I keep getting the following error message when I try to run the script:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

My script is displayed below, if anyone can suggest what I might be doing wrong?

I have also tried inserting the Unicode escape sequences for Telugu characters in my script, and that didn't work either.

My code is below:

```
import os

# Set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = r"C:\MYJSON.json"


import csv
from google.cloud import texttospeech_v1
from pydub import AudioSegment
import io

# Initialize Google Cloud TTS client
client = texttospeech_v1.TextToSpeechClient()

# Initialize an empty audio segment
final_audio = AudioSegment.empty()

# Read CSV and Generate Audio
with open("C:\\testscript.csv", 'r', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile)  # Read the CSV as a regular reader
    next(reader)  # Skip the header row
    
    for row in reader:
        phrase = row[0]  # Access the first column (Column A) for the phrase
        lang = row[1]    # Access the second column (Column B) for the language

        if phrase and lang:
            # Determine the language code based on the language specified in the CSV
            if lang == 'English':
                lang_code = 'en-US'
                voice_name = 'en-US-Wavenet-D'
            elif lang == 'Telugu':
                lang_code = 'te-IN'
                voice_name = 'te-IN-Standard-B'
            else:
                continue  # Skip rows with unrecognized languages

            # Generate and append audio
            synthesis_input = texttospeech_v1.SynthesisInput(text=phrase)
            voice = texttospeech_v1.VoiceSelectionParams(language_code=lang_code, name=voice_name)
            audio_config = texttospeech_v1.AudioConfig(audio_encoding=texttospeech_v1.AudioEncoding.MP3)
            response = client.synthesize_speech(input=synthesis_input, voice=voice, audio_config=audio_config)
            audio = AudioSegment.from_mp3(io.BytesIO(response.audio_content))
            final_audio += audio + AudioSegment.silent(duration=3000)

# Save Final Audio
final_audio.export("C:\\audio2.wav", format="wav")
```

Comment: Include the full traceback message so we can see the failing line.

Comment: I loaded your code and did not get a syntax error. It failed of course, but not because of syntax. I don't think this code generated that error. Post the traceback and prove me wrong!

Answer (score 0):

The error message you're encountering, **"SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape,"** is a common Python error related to how string literals are interpreted and how backslashes are handled in string representations.

To resolve this issue, you can escape the backslashes in your file path by using double backslashes `\\\\` instead of single backslashes `\\`. Here's the modified line:

```
os.environ["GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS"] = r"C:\\MYJSON.json"
```

Comment: You are correct about the error, but I don't think it applies in this case. OP is already using the raw string `r"C:\MYJSON.json"`, so the backslash is not a special escape character. Adding an additional backslash as you suggest would create two backslashes in the compiled string. The problem is with an unescaped `\uxxxx` which does not appaer in OP's example code.